# 3D visualization in browser

Tags: browser, 3d

I am looking for solutions for 3D visualizations in web browsers.
For now I just need to do research about this topic, i.e. I need to know how many solutions exist and which of these are good and why?
Thanks

Comment: WebGL: http://delicious.com/popular/webgl

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Brief overview of 3D on the web:

[VRML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VRML). An HTML-style markup language for 3D models that was supposed to be the amazing cyberspace future of the web, back when we still thought what the web needed to be popular was just to totally change everything about it. We were idiots. VRML is all but dead.

[Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_Flash). JVMs from 1.3 can run the Java3D engine in applets. With the decline in prevalence of desktop Java I have yet to see this in the wild.

[Flash](https://java3d.dev.java.net/). 3D-primitive support in Flash 10; libraries that hack it in earlier Flash versions, and provide higher-level engine features. (Papervision, Sandy et al.) This is how the majority of in-browser 3D is done today.

[CSS](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-3d-transforms/). WebKit provides a perspective transform feature to CSS, which has been proposed for standardisation. Won't offer anything like full 3D engine features of course, but the capability to integrate with HTML content in the page is interesting.

[O3D](http://code.google.com/apis/o3d/). Google's experimental 3D engine browser plugin.

[WebGL](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/). Proposed binding of standard OpenGL to JavaScript and HTML5 canvas. Of interest in that you can use it in plain JavaScript with no plugins, but it's pretty low-level. Currently only available in in-development browser snapshots.

Others. There are gaming 3D engines that have been packaged into a plugin, eg. [Unity](http://unity3d.com/webplayer/), and a few sundry proprietary-format model viewer plugins.

Comment: Add 3D pdf from adobe and u3d - but nothing has really caught on.

Answer (score 1):

Open standard [webgl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL),
if you are prepared to download a plugin - lots and lots

Nothing immediately leaps out for maps, a good place to start is [opensourcegis](http://opensourcegis.org/),

Comment: I forgot to notice one more info. This what i am looking for is related to GIS ie. i will have one map and my job will be to implement some operation with it. Maybe this will be just change i camera position, virtual walk throught this map or something like this. is this possible?

Comment: ok 
this address http://opensourcegis.org/ have a more than two hundred link. Can you save up my time and give me a couple of link where I should start my research

Answer (score 1):

Unity3D is a game engine that is (relatively) easy to use and builds to multiple platforms including the web (provided you install a plugin).

http://unity3d.com/

Answer (score 0):

X3DOM is plug-in free, supports a lot of X3D (not prototypes) and is written in web browser javascript (where you can do all the prototype stuff you like).  Cobweb is an ES6 JavaScript library which supports VRML2 (except collisions last I checked).  Cobweb is plug-in free and runs in firefox.  Both of these tools are written in WebGL.  You may have to convert your event code to X3D.  In x3dom, you may have to call x3dom.reload() if you load elements (X3D and Scene) programmatically.