# Publishing a rgl interactive 3d plot to the web

Tags: r, web, host, rgl, gwidgets

I'm looking to see if something is possible, or some ideas if it isn't...

I've used the rgl package to generate an interactive 3d plot that you can rotate to look at the data from different angles.

I would like to be able to somehow publish this (or something similar) to the web to allow other to log on to the site and interact with the graph. Is this sort of thing possible?

I was playing around with the gWidgetsWWW package before which lets you use R as the back end of a website, but I'm not sure if this would be able to embed something as advanced as an RGL plot.

Ideally this would be on the web, but it doesn't have to - i.e. if it was possible to package the actual plot in some format and send it on to people.

Are there any ways to achieve this or can anyone think of a better approach? (Are there any non-R solutions I could look into that would give the same sort of output as rgl?)

Let me know if you need any more info. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like vrmlgen might help, but you probably need to have a VRML viewer application in your web browser. VRML was the new hotness about 15 years ago, but vrmlgen is only a few years old at most...

http://www.jstatsoft.org/v36/i08/paper

Some of the answers to this SO Q might help too:

[3D visualization in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603948/3d-visualization-in-browser)

Comment: Thanks for this, VEML looks good but unfortunately it isn't an option as we haven't yet upgraded to the latest version of R and that isn't an option either at the moment. I ended up using [CanvasXpress](http://canvasxpress.org/) to get around it. Basically prepared and aggregated the data in R and then used R to print out the data in the JSON (using rJSON package) format that CanvasXpress requires, a little awkward overall it seems to work quite well. Thanks again!