# 3-dimension construction with programming language

Tags: 3d-reconstruction

Ihave images (pictures) taken with  computerized axial tomography' (CAT) scan,and i want to release a construction 3d from these pictures, first of all i want to know which programming language is the best open cv or open gL?
tkanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I you mean "made available for public" as "release", then I suggest to use web interface. A good overview of technologies that are used for 3D visualizations on the web can be found in the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603948/3d-visualization-in-browser).

Comment: I think i will do it first in matlab,